# How can I pump 1000 watts in the ground

Tags: ground

I have heard of using the ground for communication with extremely low frequency waves. They said 100 watts gives you a km and 1000 watts gives you 10 km. How can I go about pumping the waves into the ground, and what would be a good frequency to operate?

Comment: It's probably VLF rather than ELF you have in mind, although even there if you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency the antenna requirements are still pretty extreme.

Comment: "They said" is incorrect data, and you will not be able to achieve large ranges, unlicensed. Review the answer below. An article in "Popular Electronics" many years ago, sent the audio output from an amplifier to an impedance  matching transformer then into the ground. Wired like an intercom.

Comment: What type of transformer would I be looking at to match the very high impedance of the ground, also, how far apart should the two ground rods be from each other

Comment: I wonder how hard it is to find that popular electronics article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Popular Electronics article I remembered described a short distance communications system made by pumping the AUDIO from an AUDIO PA into the ground through two ground connections about 20 feet apart. To achieve an approximate match into the earth, they used an audio output transformer turned around backwards.

The amplifier had something like a 3 to 8ohm output impedance meant to drive a speaker system. Feeding the amp's output into the transformer gave something around 3,000 ohms...far from a match of earth resistance between the ground connections, however it DID work.

I was a kid but could NOT resist trying this. I scrapped an AC/DC record player and used its 5 watt (probably 3 watt), amplifier into the added matching transformer. I used one cold water pipe and a ground rod about 20 feet away from the pipe to feed the audio into the ground.

A neighbor kid built up a similar system and we were able to talk about 500 feet using high impedance headphones hooked across two ground connections.

AC hum and many, man other signals such as lightning whilstlers, large motors turning on and off, and who knows what else interfered with communications. We eventually used switches on each end to swap the amplifier's output with the high impedance headphones....sort of like an antenna transfer switch.

We wanted to try filtering out some of the noise but at 12 years old, neither of us had a clue how to accomplish such a thing. After a summer of playing with the system we decided to get into ham radio. I became WA4GZV, and my friend became WA4GWG. Needless to say, we talked anywhere we wanted to after that.  we are still friends today. He is an engineer with a defense contractor and I am retired from Motorola.

Life was fun back then and still is today!

Answer (score 2):

It's really not so easy to do that.  You can't just pump energy into the ground; you have to have an antenna of some sort to transmit with.  And for very low frequency, you need an antenna that is very, very long.  Hundreds of meters to kilometers.  And it's not going to be very efficient, either, so you're going to need an amplifier capable of transmitting at 10 kW or more to get 1 kW of radiated power.

In terms of pumping energy into the ground; there was an installation that the US used to transmit to submarines via ELF.  The antennas were 14 or 28 miles long.  The transmitter was located in the middle of the antenna, and the far ends were grounded so the current could return through the earth.  It's not an easy thing to build, and it's horribly inefficient.  The ELF transmitter only actually transmitted at about 1 watt, even though the transmitter consumed several MW.